# Copy to Clipboard on hybrid apps and browsers

Tags: clipboard, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm coding with `ionic` framework and `ngCordova` and targeting to both mobile devices and browsers.
When the user presses a button I want to copy text to the clipboard.

I'm aware that ngCordova is mainly for [mobile devices](http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/), but is there a way to run the same code for the purpose above on both platforms without also using `zeroClipboard` and `ngClip`?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because browsers has limits on clipboard use from JavaScript as a fundamental security measure. There is no way around this except utilities such as zeroClipboard.

Comment: Maybe someday cordova will add support for web browsers.. thanks!